# How to get a field value from FieldDescriptor and Value in protoreflect.Range?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have a proto:

```
message Foo {
  oneof bar {
    BarA bar_a = 1;
    BarB bar_b = 2;
  }
}

message BarA {
  string text = 1;
}

message BarB {
  int num = 1;
}
```

Then the code:

```
foo = &Foo{
    Bar: &Foo_BarA{
        BarA: &BarA{
            Text: "text",
        },
    },
}
md := foo.ProtoReflect()
md.Range(func(fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, v protoreflect.Value) bool {

}
```

Inside `md.Range`, how do I get the field value from the `fd, v` pair? For example when it iterates over the `Bar` field, I want to get a `BarA` object and retrieve `text`. I need to use `Range` because I'm also using `FieldOptions`.

**Update with more info**

My first proto is that I'm actually working with (the above protos are contrived examples) is:

```
extend google.protobuf.FieldOptions {
  string field_name = 50000;
}

extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
  string template_name = 50000;
  Type type = 50001;
}

message SendNotificationRequest {
  Type type = 1;
  Template template = 2;
}

enum Type {
  TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  TYPE_EMAIL = 1;
  TYPE_PUSH = 2;
}

message Template {
  oneof template {
    EmailTemplate email_template = 1;
    PushTemplate push_template = 2;
  }
}

message EmailTemplate {
  option (type) = TYPE_EMAIL;

  oneof template {
    WelcomeEmailTemplate welcome_email_template = 1;
  }
}

message WelcomeEmailTemplate {
  option (template_name) = "welcome_email";

  Field title = 1 [(field_name) = "main_title"];
  Field user_name = 2 [(field_name) = "name"];
}

message Field {
  oneof value {
    string str = 1;
    bool bool = 2;
    int64 num = 3;
  }
}
```

My second proto, part of another service+project, is:

```
message CreateNotificationRequest {
  Type type = 1;
  string template_name = 2;
  map<string, Field> template_fields = 2; 
}

enum Type {
  TYPE_UNSPECIFIED = 0;
  TYPE_EMAIL = 1;
  TYPE_PUSH = 2;
}

message Field {
  oneof value {
    string str = 1;
    bool bool = 2;
    int64 num = 3;
  }
}
```

I want to write one function that can convert any `SendNotificationRequest` to a `CreateNotificationRequest`. Let's call `SendNotificationRequest`'s import alias `api` and `CreateNotificationRequest`'s `api2`. I cannot change `api2`.

Not too relevant but I made the non-required decision to use typed `Template` for my service (`api`) instead of the generic map of `api2`, as I felt typed classes are more maintainable and less error-prone.

For an example conversion, this

```
&api.SendNotificationRequest{
    Type: api.Type_TYPE_EMAIL,
    Template:   &api.Template {
        Template: &api.Template_EmailTemplate{
            EmailTemplate: &api.EmailTemplate{
                Template: &api.EmailTemplate_WelcomeEmailTemplate{
                    Title:     &api.Field{Value: &api.Placeholder_Str{Text: "Welcome Bob"}},
                    UserName:     &api.Field{Value: &api.Placeholder_Str{Text: "Bob Jones"}},
                },
            },
        },
    },
}
```

should convert to:

```
&api2.CreateNotificationRequest{
    Type: api2.Type_TYPE_EMAIL,
    TemplateName: "welcome_email",
    Template:   map[string]*api2.Field{
        "main_title":     &api2.Field{Value: &api.Placeholder_Str{Text: "Welcome Bob"}},
        "name":     &api2.Field{Value: &api.Placeholder_Str{Text: "Bob Jones"}},
    },
}
```

There may be new oneofs of `EmailTemplate`, and templates like `WelcomeEmailTemplate` may change its fields. But I want to write one function that doesn't need to be updated for those changes.

I believe this is very possible from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69139530/how-to-get-a-field-value-from-fielddescriptor-and-value-in-protoreflect-range#:%7E:text=md.Range(func(fd%20protoreflect.FieldDescriptor%2C%20v%20protoreflect.Value)%20bool%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20barA%2C%20ok%20%3A%3D%20v.Message().Interface().(*BarA)%3B%20ok%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20fmt.Println(barA.Text)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20true%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)).

I can `nest md.Range` on a `SendNotificationRequest` and its fields to process all its fields, and write a switch case to convert any `Field` oneof. I can also fetch FieldOption and MessageOption. While this happens, I build the `CreateNotificationRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value of `BarA` with:

```golang
    md.Range(func(fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, v protoreflect.Value) bool {
        w := v.Message().Get(fd.Message().Fields().ByNumber(1))
        fmt.Println(w) // prints "text"
        return false
    })
```

This works straight away because your proto message has only one populated field (`bar_a`). If you have more populated fields, you should add more checks. E.g. check that the current `FieldDescriptor` is the one you are looking for. A more robust implementation might look like:

```
    md.Range(func(fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, v protoreflect.Value) bool {
        if fd.Name() == "bar_a" {
            if field := fd.Message().Fields().ByName("text"); field != nil {
                w := v.Message().Get(field)
                fmt.Println(w) // text
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    })
```

Using `ByName` instead of `ByNumber` is debatable, since the field name doesn't play a role in the serialization, but IMO it makes for more readable code.

---

As an alternative, you can directly get the concrete value of the field by type-asserting the interface held in `v`:

```
md.Range(func(fd protoreflect.FieldDescriptor, v protoreflect.Value) bool {
        if barA, ok := v.Message().Interface().(*BarA); ok {
            fmt.Println(barA.Text)
            return false
        }
        return true
    })
```

Comment: By the way, could I get the "real" value? Something like `barA := v.(*pb.BarA)`, I know this not works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @p1gd0g you should be able to do that with `v.Message().Interface().(*pb.BarA)` (I didn't test this)

Comment: @blackgreen Wow, thanks for all the solutions! To elaborate my problem, I want to generically convert any `Foo` Message to another Message type that is very similar structurally wise, and requires knowledge of values of my custom FieldOption and MessageOption. `Foo` will only have the `Bar` field, which has the same number of levels of fields among its oneofs (`BarA` or `BarB`), but I may keep adding new fields to any level of `Bar`. The set of proto types will remain the same.

Comment: I don't want to update the reflection code each time fields are added to the `Bar` proto. Thus your first two solutions won't be ideal.

However your third solution seems perfect. I just need to keep nesting `md.Range` to process all levels of fields of `Foo`, and write a switch case to process all field types. I can fetch my FieldOption+MessageOption and build my other Message at the same time.

Does this seem like a good solution for my problem?

Comment: @onepiece I'm not sure I completely understand, maybe it would be best to edit your question to include more details and code samples. Anyway: when you say "but I may keep adding new fields to any level of Bar", do you mean adding fields to the `oneof bar`? E.g. `BarC bar_c = 3` etc?

Comment: @blackgreen I appended details to my question under `Update with more info`. Hopefully that clarifies what I want to do.